# Why does a newly created EF-entity throw an ID is null exception when trying to save?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I´m trying out entity framework included in VS2010 but ´ve hit a problem with my database/model generated from the graphical interface.

When I do:

```
user = dataset.UserSet.CreateObject();
user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
dataset.UserSet.AddObject(user);
dataset.SaveChanges();
```

{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'BarSoc2.dbo.UserSet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

The table i´m inserting into looks like so:

```
-- Creating table 'UserSet'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserSet] (
    [Id] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Username] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Password] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'UserSet'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserSet]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_UserSet]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO
```

Am I creating the object in the wrong way or doing something else basic wrong?

Comment: Why are you using CreateObject() instead of just new UserSet()?

Comment: I assumed it was a more correct way, is it not needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to set the ID property manually.  It should be set automatically when you save.  I assume you are using the standard template for Entity Framework, and not the Self-tracking entities template or POCOs template. If so, something along the following lines would seem more appropriate:

```
User user = new User();
dataset.AddToUsers(user);
dataset.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Apperently something goes very wrong when you set the id yourself. AddToUsers is deprecated though.

Answer (score 8):

On the model for the fields which is defined as key, add the following attribute.
This key which is not marked as IDENTITY in database, Entity Framework give the exception

```
[Key]
[Display(Name = "Id")]     
[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```